# running .sh file from jenkins - operation not permitted

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh

I am facing an issue while trying to generate an iOS app from the command line using the ".sh" file from Jenkins Execute shell. Every time I get operation not permitted. but I can able to run the same file from the command line without any error. please help.[attachement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8SG4.png)

Comment: Check for the permission to run that script file. Whether the user has access to run it.

Comment: Yes, the permissions are also there. but I face this error, particularly in Jenkins.